# ODBC Command does not throw error

Tags: vb6, odbc, db2

I'm working on a VB6 executable that uses ODBC to update a DB2 Table.  When trying to update a row that does not exist the program does not throw an error as would be expected.  Why would this happen?

```
objAdoConn.Execute("Update T1234 Set A = 'X' Where B = 'y'");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this is a valid SQL statement that results in "0 rows affected". Which is success.

Answer (score 3):

From a SQL point of view, there is nothing wrong with that command - it just doesn't update anything, which is a perfectly valid outcome.

Answer (score 2):

The [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953019/odbc-command-does-not-throw-error/953047#953047) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953019/odbc-command-does-not-throw-error/953043#953043) are correct: it's a valid SQL statement that just doesn't affect any records. If you want to know how many records are affected, use the optional [RecordsAffected parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675023(VS.85).aspx) like this:

```
Dim n As Long
objAdoConn.Execute("Update T1234 Set A = 'X' Where B = 'y'", n)
If n=0 Then MsgBox "No records affected!"
```